# Div tag content not showing on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to display the data of a div tag on a href click, the id is dynamically made. But the div tag is not responding. The sequence of the code is as below. The file is the .tpl file.

```js
        function editPickUpAddress(divId)
        {
            ("#pickupAddressForm_"+divId).show();
        }
```

```html
<a href style="float:right;margin-top:-20px;margin-right:100px;" onclick="editPickUpAddress({$item.profile_id});">Edit</a>

 <div id="pickupAddressForm_{$item.profile_id}" style="display:none">
   //some content to display
   </div>
```

Comment: `$` missing `$("#pickupAddressForm_"+divId)`

Answer (score 1):

After cleaning up your snippet and including jQuery, the code works as intended. Also note the `href="#"` which prevents the anchor tag from navigating to another page.

```js
function editPickUpAddress(divId) {
  $("#pickupAddressForm_" + divId).show();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" onclick="editPickUpAddress(1);">Edit</a>

<div id="pickupAddressForm_1" style="display:none">
  //some content to display
</div>
```